# Unlink an existing firebase app?

Tags: firebase, google-fabric

I want to "Link to new or existing Firebase project & app"
but the crashlytics dashboard told me my project is already linked,

how to unlink my existing project ?

[image: fabric]

Comment: Thanks Julien. Hold tight for a couple more days. We are working to add the un-link button into the Firebase integrations section in your Firebase dashboard. It may be live by the time you read this :)

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to get it resolved?

Comment: did you fix it, yet, @ToddBurner? I can't find the un-link button in the Firebase integrations section.

Comment: @ToddBurner any updates ?

Answer (score 12):

To unlink your Fabric app from Firebase, follow the following steps:

1. Go to The Firebase project settings
2. Go to Integrations
3. Select the Fabric "Manage" link
4. Click the "Unlink Fabric App"

[image: Firebase settings]
[image: Unlink Fabric]

Comment: Is that option still there, @Ockert - Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @lundzern it is as of today

Comment: Sometimes, it does not seem on Integrations list. In that case, you can unlink it with this link like : https://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/1853317-unlink-fabric-and-firebase-projects

Comment: @okarakose this article appears to have been removed. Fabric is also not appearing in my integrations.

Answer (score 4):

Very late but if someone still having this problem:

1- try to unlink on firebase dashboard as explanined in this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49229545/5679560

2- if the option to remove fabric doesn't appear use this direct link

https://fabric.io/remove_firebase_crashlytics?clientId=`CLIENT_ID`&projectId=`PROJECT_ID`

`CLIENT_ID` is your Firebase Client ID. This begins with "android:" or "ios:" and is followed by either your package name (Android) or bundle ID (iOS)

`PROJECT_ID` is your app’s containing Firebase project ID, which can be found by going to Project Settings. This is also present in the URL of your Firebase console, i.e. https://console.firebase.google.com/project/

you can check more info in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50003432/5679560