# Fabric won't let me link my Firebase app

Tags: firebase, google-fabric

I have an app on my Firebase project that I'm trying to link to Fabric.

When I go to Fabric -> Firebase -> Set up integration and select the app, it says "Already linked".

But if I go to Firebase console -> Project settings -> Integrations -> Fabric, I don't see it linked there. I do see some other apps linked, but not the one that I'm trying to link right now.

Any idea why this could be happening? If I had an old Firebase <-> Fabric link, I should at least see it here and be able to remove it, but there's nothing there. So why does Fabric think that my app is already linked, when it's clearly not?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Paul from Fabric here. My recommendation would be to unlink your app and try again.

You can unlink by using the following URL:
https://fabric.io/remove_firebase_crashlytics?clientId=CLIENT_ID&projectId=PROJECT_ID

- `CLIENT_ID` is your Firebase Client ID.
  This begins with "android:" or "ios:" and is followed by either your package name (Android) or bundle ID (iOS)
  [image: example of CLIENT_ID]
- `PROJECT_ID` is your app’s containing Firebase project ID, which can be found by going to Project Settings. This is also present in the URL of your Firebase console, i.e. `https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<projectId>`
  [image: example of PROJECT_ID]

For example, with these values:

- clientId: ios:com.remove.crashlytics.1
- projectId: test-removing-crashlytics

The link becomes: https://fabric.io/remove_firebase_crashlytics?clientId=ios:com.remove.crashlytics.1&projectId=test-removing-crashlytics

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. When I tried to do it, it says "Unable to find app my_app_id in project myproject-97eb5. Return to Firebase Console and try again." I had no trouble finding project ID in firebase console, but I wasn't sure what's supposed to be the client id, so I tried both - the app package and also the "App ID" displayed in the firebase console, which looks like random numbers and letters separated with : and "android" somewhere in between.

Comment: @Guy Sorry for the confusion. I've updated my answer to be more specific about which values should populate these fields. Let me know if this is helpful for you!

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm :)

Comment: This is the only trick that worked for a certain app of mine. Fabric.io said the app was not linked, but the app ID was already taken (as if taken by another app). Firebase showed the Crashlytics graphics with zero crashes. Using the link reset the situation so I could re-link from Firebase again as I did successfully for other apps.

Comment: @buser i have the same issue, except when i click the red button "Reset Firebase Crashlytics" it changes to "This app was not linked", and i can't continue

Comment: Same as @Godfather here. :(

Comment: The issue for me unlinking the app was that I was trying to do it with a google account that did not manage the apps in firebase. Make sure you are using the right account before unlinking from this link.

Comment: hi guys, I go to this link:
https://fabric.io/firebase_migration (I removed parameters for security reasons)

Sign in With Google Button is not working at all. It does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this [link](https://fabric.io/firebase_migration/status) > scroll down and under "Migrated Firebase apps" > click the "Manage Links" button that will take you to the Firebase Project > Settings  > Integrations and click the "Unlink Fabric app" on the right side of the screen[image]

Answer (score -1):

There is a new option introduced to Firebase that allows easy management of integrations. This option can be found under "Integrations" tab in Firebase Project Settings.

[image]

Open this tab in the project that has the Fabric integration already and you can tap on the "Manage" button for fabric and you will see the unlink option.

Comment: I rmoved the app on fabric first and the "unlink" is now hidden, and if I click it before it gets hidden It says "Error, something happened", any ideas?