# Crashlytics from Fabric to Firebase

Tags: firebase, migration, crashlytics, google-fabric

My ios application uses crashlytics and fabric. I wanted to migrate Crashlytics in firebase. During configuration I say that I have not crashlytics in my App. An get instruction how add crashlytics to my app. Now when I’m trying to return at the first step I’m getting an error “Action failed”. How can I link my Fabric account and firebase?

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. If you're currently using Crashlytics within Fabric, then you shouldn't try to migrate yet. Try using this unlinking flow to see if that corrects it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50000410/fabric-wont-let-me-link-my-firebase-app/50003432#50003432

Comment: Hi, Mike. Thank you for you answer. I opened the recommended page and pressed button “Reset Firebase Crashlytics”. Unfortunatelly I got an error “There was an error”. It seems to me the problem in Firebase. I need to stop the proccess of adding new crashlytics to my app. But I don’t know how I can do it.

Comment: Since that didn't work, best to contact Firebase Support so that we can dig in more.

Answer (score -3):

**This help to migrate fabric to Firebase for ios Application**

Step 1. Remove the Fabric initialization code.
We’ll first need to remove Fabric from our Xcode project settings.

Start by opening your app in Xcode.
Remove the Crashlytics Run Script Build Phase from your Xcode project’s Build Phases.
In your AppDelegate.swift, remove your Fabric initialization code by removing the import Fabric and import Crashlytics statements, as well as any Fabric.with() statements.

step 2:
To set up Firebase Crashlytics, follow along in the Firebase Documentation on Getting started with Firebase Crashlytics.

If your Podfile already contains pods for Fabric and Crashlytics, replace them with these version-specific pods:

```
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.7'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.2'
```

Once you finish setting up Firebase Crashlytics, you can test your implementation by forcing a test crash in your app.

[ios fabric to firebase migration](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/examples/cannonball/)

Go through above link it will helpful to you.